# 7 Wonders, Babylon Side B: Using Resources and Coins from 2nd Wonder

Tags: 7-wonders

When using side B of Babylon, after acquiring the 2nd Wonder Stage, I am able to purchase the last two cards in my had. Can I then:
1) Use coins from the sixth card (which I burn) to pay for the seventh card?
2) Use a resource of the sixth card that I payed for to acquire the seventh card?

Example:
John (playing with Babylon on side B, already completed his 2nd Wonder Stage) has three coins left in his sixth turn. He knows that he cannot use any coins his neighbors may give him at the completion of turn number six. He is holding two cards, neither of which he can afford. However, if he trashes the sixth card to gain 3 coins, he can afford to purchase the seventh card using resources from his neighbors. Is this allowed?

Comment: Yes, as per the duplicate question. The answer from the designer covers this very case. Perhaps the duplicate question should have a more informative title.